# Does the "Cartridge" pattern exist?

Tags: naming-conventions, design-patterns

AndroMDA uses the term "cartridge" (e.g. for out-of-the-box NHibernate support).
As I understood it, it takes an API/component, wrapps it, never adds new features, simplifies it, often taking away "the full power", but works well for most cases.

My questions:

- Is the term widely used?
- Can one properly define it?
- Should the suffix "Cartridge" be used in class/method names?

An example: is the following Base64 helper a cartridge for Base64 conversion?
You give away all the power for performance-tuning, but if you simply want to decode a simple (and small) string it works fine:

Usage:

```
   Base64StringCartridge.Decode(input);
```

Implementation

```
public static string Decode(string data)
{
    try
    {
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        System.Text.Decoder utf8Decode = encoder.GetDecoder();

        byte[] todecode_byte = System.Convert.FromBase64String(data);
        int charCount = utf8Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);
        char[] decoded_char = new char[charCount];
        utf8Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length, decoded_char, 0);
        string result = new String(decoded_char);
        return result;
    }

    catch
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called the [Facade Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). Presumably the AndroMDA folks are big fans of old video game machines...